# Grails 2.2.5- Cannot install easy-grid plugin

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm trying to install easy-grid 1.6.6  just like the readme on github
https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid/blob/master/README.md. I'm using grails 2.2.5

My BuildConfig.groovy looks like this:

```
...grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    plugins {
        compile ":grails-melody:1.52.0", ":gwt:0.6.1", 
        ":easygrid:1.6.6", ":export:1.6", ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
        /*compile ":easygrid:1.6.2"*/
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"  // This won't work after Grail 2.3.1, look it up 
        //build ':elasticsearch:0.0.3.1'
        if (Environment.getCurrent() in [Environment.DEVELOPMENT]) {
            runtime ':elasticsearch:0.0.3.1'
        }
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    }
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }...
```

But I'm getting this error when I refresh the dependencies:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.5
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE\medhome-ui/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\codenarc-0.8.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\csv-0.3.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\dto-0.2.4/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\grails-melody-1.52.0/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\gwt-0.6.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\hibernate-2.2.5/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jquery-1.8.3/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jsecurity-0.4.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\mail-1.0/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\settings-1.4/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\svn-1.0.0.M1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\tomcat-2.2.5/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\yui-2.7.0.1/lib/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/easygrid/ivy-1.6.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/easygrid/jars/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/easygrid/bundles/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/easygrid-1.6.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/easygrid-1.6.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/easygrid-1.6.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-easygrid/tags/RELEASE_1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-easygrid/tags/RELEASE_1.6.6/grails-easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#easygrid;1.6.6!easygrid.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/easygrid/1.6.6/easygrid-1.6.6.zip
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#export;1.6
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE\medhome-ui/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\codenarc-0.8.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\csv-0.3.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\dto-0.2.4/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\grails-melody-1.52.0/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\gwt-0.6.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\hibernate-2.2.5/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jquery-1.8.3/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jsecurity-0.4.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\mail-1.0/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\settings-1.4/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\svn-1.0.0.M1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\tomcat-2.2.5/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\yui-2.7.0.1/lib/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/ivy-1.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/jars/export-1.6.zip
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/bundles/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/export-1.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/export-1.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.6.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/export-1.6.zip
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-export/tags/RELEASE_1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-export/tags/RELEASE_1.6/grails-export-1.6.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip
    ==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE\medhome-ui/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\codenarc-0.8.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\csv-0.3.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\dto-0.2.4/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\grails-melody-1.52.0/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\gwt-0.6.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\hibernate-2.2.5/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jquery-1.8.3/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\jsecurity-0.4.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\mail-1.0/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\settings-1.4/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\svn-1.0.0.M1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\tomcat-2.2.5/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\projects\medhome\plugins\yui-2.7.0.1/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/jquery-ui/ivy-1.10.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/jquery-ui/jars/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/lib/org.grails.plugins/jquery-ui/bundles/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\src\libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/jquery-ui-1.10.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5\dist/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Users\u0289763\.grails\2.2.5\cached-installed-plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
      C:\Apps\grails-2.2.5/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jquery-ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui-1.10.3.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3!jquery-ui.zip:
- org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.10.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needed both of these repositories  under the repositories:

```
repositories { 
grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"
  mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" 
...
}
```